# How to migrate extra tables in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I have situation where i have already migrated my tables to database , Now i created one more table and i want to push it also so I did run again `php artisan migrate` but this time it throws an error of previous table already exists , 
and i can not **rollback** and migrate again i have data in my other tables

So what can I do , is there any other way ?

I tried

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migration works in batch so let's say you had migration for:

- Table 1
- Table 2
- Table 3

and you ran `php artisan migrate`, It will create those tables under one batch, lets call it `Batch 1`

Now let's say you added one more migration for new table:

- Table 4

This time when you run `php artisan migrate`, a status is checked internally to see what new table migrations have been created which are not under some batch already.

It will check Batch 1, as thats the only batch created so far and will create new tables under second bacth, lets call it `Batch 2`

So it will be something like:

Table 1 |
Table 2 | --> Batch 1
Table 3 |

Table 4 | --> Batch 2

and so on...

So, you must have done something else than what I have listed above.

If you have created the table manually in the database and then also created migration, of course `php artisan migrate` will give error that `table already exists`, in that case you dont need to run migration as you already have the table.

In any case run: `php artisan migrate:status`, which will let you know the exact status of migration and issues with it.

You can also check `migrations` table in your DB which also specifies the batches under which the tables were created.

Comment: yeah , I guess  , I get it now how it works , thank you I didnt know about batches , i run status command I see it clearly , and Now i know the problem ty

Comment: Yup also rollback happens in batches so if you run rollback, it will only rollback the latest batch..glad it helped

Comment: yeah , the table was created manually and 
I thought it might have migrated before as i am working on existing project